# permissions don't work with my code. Member doesn't exist

Tags: discord.js

so I've been trying to make a bot for Discord, and my kick and ban function work, but the permissions don't work. Tried to repair it somehow, but it got worse and it was going into an infinite loop.

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith('+kick')) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);

      if (member) {
        member
          .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {

            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {

        message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
  }
  }
});
```

This is my code. I want to make it go to further messages only if you have kick members permission. There are many codes on the internet but they seem to break my code somehow.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: version: discord.js@12.2.0
and with this code I have here, it works, but when I am trying to do something like
```if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") {
}``` it throws an error and says that member is undefinded and message is undefined.

Comment: Well, where are you putting that if statement?

Comment: I am going to edit it

Comment: should work, can you paste the exact error?

Comment: nevermind, I was putting this code in the wrong line. I fixed it! The code that is up is correct now.